# Make diffrent picturebox a Parent of Another Label And make backColor Transparent?

Tags: c#, winforms

So i had a small Styling problem while making my Engine UI in c# .
the thing is that i use the following to make a label backColor Transparent  :

```
label.Parent = mypicturebox;

label.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

it worked for everything that has a parent of mypicturebox  such as title .. close and minimize labels .

but when i tried to make my footer label's backcolor transparent too it did not work !

Any ideas ?

[image]

Comment: you probably misspelled `Background` with `Foreground`

Comment: show us the code where you set the header and the code where you set the footer. so we can compare

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! Did you also set the Parent?

Comment: It worked perfectly.  Green text on a transparent background.  So green on green, hard to read.  Change the label's ForeColor to black.  What happened to the top label is harder to reverse-engineer.

Comment: Btw, if you set the Parent of a Label, you don't need to set `[Label].BackColor = Color.Transparent;`. The *transparency* feature is applied automatically (i.e,  the Parent's surface features will be implicitly inherited. i.e, it will be painted as the Parent's).

Comment: @HansPassant Hello , I just Changed manully the text color of my header's title label to black that's what happend there .
and Actually  in the footer i tried black color before posting this did not work aswell !

Comment: @sLw   

                        `Minimizer.Parent = TitlePic; 
   Minimizer.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

   titre.Parent = TitlePic;
   titre.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
   titre.ForeColor = Color.Black;

   Closer.Parent = TitlePic;
   Closer.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
   //Footer
   FbBtn.Parent = FooterPic;
   FbBtn.BackColor = Color.Transparent;`
// TitlePic = GreenHeader's Picture // titre = the actualy label in header [ALGO -C ] //Fb.Btn = the footer label that im having prob with .

Comment: @TaW hey  its WinForms ! Thanks for the advice :) .

Comment: @Jimi Totally agree with you , but sometimes in some cases Mostly when a buggy computer .. it does not work (happend to a friend) .